# specificity issue w/ CSS opacities: overriding the opacity of the parent div

Tags: html, css

I have a div (id=alertPanel) that I want to put in front of another div (id=captchaPanel). The captchaPanel div has an opacity of .25 -- but I want the front alert DIV tp be 100% opaque. (I am going for a lightbox-like effect). Both DIVs have IDs and are not in classes. I assign the back div an opacity of .25 and the front div an opacity of 1 -- but the front div still is not opaque (in Chrome and Safari at least... so likely also in FF and IE). I am making an ID-specific rule in a simple application of CSS, so I am confused about why I am getting this result.

Here is the HTML:

```
      <div id='captchaPanel'>

        <div id='alertPanel'>
            in the middle
        </div>

        //some HTML

    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    #alertPanel
    {

        height: 10%;
        width: 10%;
        margin-left: auto ;
        z-index:1;
        margin-right: auto ;
        position: absolute;
        background-color:blue;
        float:none;
        opacity:1 !important;
    }

    #captchaPanel
    {
        height: 60%;
        width: 57%;
        background-color:#580200;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-left: auto ;
        margin-right: auto ;
        border-radius:15px;
        opacity:.05; 
        z-index:-1;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A child will inherit the opacity of its parent.

If you are only using colors, change the #captchaPanel to use rgba:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/eNHND/)

You could also change the markup so that alertPanel`is not a descendant of`captchaPanel`

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id='captchaPanel'>//some html</div>
    <div id='alertPanel'>in the middle</div>
</div>
```

[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/davidcl64/eNHND/2/)

Comment: Well that explains it. So maybe I should wrap captcha panel in another div and have the alert panel be the child of this new panel div?